# Why we should declare name of queue in receiver?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am learning RabbitMQ. I can't understand why in [example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html) of `receive_logs.py` we setting type of the exchange:

```
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='logs',
                         exchange_type='fanout')
```

and binding name of queue with this exchange:

```
channel.queue_bind(exchange='logs',
                   queue=queue_name)
```

The sender already created exchange with type `exchange`. Why we need to set type again? 
Why we need to do `queue_bind` if the type of exchange `fanout`? That's means that every queue in it will get message, but here we specify name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `fanout` exchanges rout messages to *every queue they are bound to*.

You are not binding exchange to a queue in producer. And that binding has to be declared somewhere - in this case it is done on consumer side.

It is not "route a message to every queue present on the broker" :) You need to bind it too.

Comment: Why we need set it to sender and for receiver?

Comment: @user1432751 see middle paragraph

Comment: so what I should write at receiver side here: `chan.basic_consume( ... )`. If I already binded all on sender.

Comment: @user1432751 Yes - if you declare the queue and the exchange-queue binding on sender side, then you do not need to re-declare them on consumer side.

Comment: yes, I understand, but what I should specify in string above? In example there is name of queue.

Comment: @user1432751 I use Java API, but for `basic_consume` you need to provide the name of queue you want to consume from. So in your design: producer knows name of queue + name of exchange; consumer knows name of queue only.